# System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Tags: salesforce, soql

```
  public void search ()
   {
    
        string searchquery='select Car_Name__c ,id  from car__c where Car_Name__c  like \'%'+ searchkey+'%\' Limit 20';
        sim=Database.query(searchquery);
        

   }
```

> System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject
> Error is in expression '{!search}' in component apex:commandButton in page simpsons_vf01_car_show: Class.Simpsons_Cl1_classCar.search: line 36, column 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the value `sim` is of type `Car__c`. You cannot assign the result of a query that returns *anything other than exactly one record* to a value whose type is an SObject. In particular, this does not make sense when you're performing a search query with a `LIMIT 20` clause.

You should type your variable as a `List<Car__c>`.